# Convert an image into 2 colors black/white

Tags: flash, pixel-bender

I am looking for a script, (modes ?), pixel bender ? that allows me to convert an movieclip/image into 2 colors (black and white).
I don't want grey scales, but really 2 colors only picture.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the [ColorMatrixFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/). It can probably be used to do exactly what you're after.